# Properly overriding WndProc

Tags: delphi, controls, wndproc

One day ago I had started to rewrite one of my old components and I decided to improve its readability.
My component is a typical `TWinControl` that has overridden `WndProc` to handle a lot of messages of my own. There are so many code for each message and it became a problem for me to read code.
So, looking for a solution to improve code inside `WndProc`, I have organized these large pieces of code in procedures that called each time when appropriate message has delivered in `WndProc`. That's how it looks now:

```
procedure TMyControl.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  case Message.Msg of        
    WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED: 
      WMWINDOWPOSCHANGED(Message);
    WM_DESTROY: 
      WMDESTROY(Message);
    WM_STYLECHANGED: 
      WMSTYLECHANGED(Message);
    //  lots of the same procedures for Windows messages
    //  ...
    MM_FOLDER_CHANGED: 
      MMFOLDERCHANGED(Message);
    MM_DIRECTORY_CHANGED: 
      MMDIRECTORYCHANGED(Message);
    //  lots of the same procedures for my own messages
    //  ...
  else
    Inherited WndProc(Message);
  end;
end;
```

Unfortunately `Inherited` word in these procedures doesn't work anymore!

**Important note:** in some of WM_XXX messages I didn't call `Inherited` to perform my own handling of such message, so code shown below will break down my efforts to implement some features.

```
procedure TMyControl.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Inherited WndProc(Message);
  case Message.Msg of        
    WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED: 
      WMWINDOWPOSCHANGED(Message);
    //  further messages
    //  ...
  end;
end;
```

I also want to avoid inserting `Inherited` after each message-ID as shown below, because it looks awful and I think there is exists more elegant way to override `WndProc`.

```
procedure TMyControl.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin      
  case Message.Msg of        
    WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED: 
    begin
      Inherited WndProc(Message);
      WMWINDOWPOSCHANGED(Message);
    end;
    //  further messages
    //  ...
  end;
end;
```

So my question is:
*how to properly override `WndProc` to have an ability to use code grouped in procedures and to be able to call for original window procedure only for some messages?*

Comment: Either use nested functions, or the `message` directive.

Comment: `Unfortunately Inherited word in these procedures doesn't work anymore` Have you remembered the `override` WndProc?

Comment: That's not it @Vasek. Asker wants to call inherited WndProc. Which is fine from the overridden WndProc, but not from some other method.

Comment: Calling `DefaultHandler` should suffice, I'd say.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/Messages_(Delphi)

Comment: @Victoria, thank you for comment. I didn't know about `DefaultHandler` before. Documentation on Embarcadero site says "DefaultHandler is called by System.TObject.Dispatch when it cannot find a method for a particular message". Probably, better way is to handle message is to call Dispatch. I will try it.

Comment: Maybe just rely on the message result (set it to 1, handled) and call the inherited WndProc in any case?

Comment: @Vasek, yes, `WndProc` has been overridden. But this is not an answer for my question.

Comment: @David, thank you for link - I will research it immediatly.

Comment: @nil, thank you for comment, but you have described situation which I would like to avoid. I want to call window procedure from procedure that handles message, but I cannot call `inherited WndProc` in such manner.

Comment: Well that was not what I was proposing. I meant in your handler procedures to just alter the `Result` of the `var Message` parameter you provide. Then, in your `WndProc` implementation at the end call `inherited WndProc(Message)`. This however relies on descendants to ignore handled messages, is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Dima, `Dispatch` does the only thing. It searches for the message handler methods and call them if found. If not, it calls `DefaultHandler`. Depends on what you want.

Comment: @nil, it was my mistake, I've never use such a trick before, so there was a problem for me to understand what you have advised. But thank you for this info!

Comment: @Victoria, answer is already here but your recommendation to use `DefaultHandler` gave me additional ability to get more info about message handling in Delphi. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As RM's answer stated, your message handling methods can call `inherited WndProc(Message)` instead of just `inherited`, and that will work fine.

However, by introducing methods with the same names as the messages they are processing, you are exposing knowledge of the specific messages you are processing.  So you may find it easier to just use [Message Methods](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods_(Delphi)#Message_Methods) instead of overriding `WndProc`, eg:

```
type
  TMyControl = class(...)
  private
    procedure WMWindowPosChanged(var Message: TMessage); message WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED;
    procedure WMDestroy(var Message: TMessage); message WM_DESTROY;
    procedure WMStyleChanged(var Message: TMessage); message WM_STYLECHANGED;
    // and so on ...
  end;
```

Your `message` methods can then call `inherited` (or not) as needed, eg:

```
procedure TMyControl.WMWindowPosChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  //...
end;
```

Comment: Well it is real trick (for me) to handle messages in this way. Yesterday [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) gave me a link where the same technique is used. Unfortunately he didn't provide its comment as answer, so I will accept your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Calling inherited WndProc from WMWINDOWPOSCHANGED will call the inherited one. So you can do it like this:

```
procedure WMWINDOWPOSCHANGED(var Message: TMessage)
begin
  // call inherited WndProc if you need to
  inherited WndProc(Message);
  .. do you own processing
end;
```

Comment: Yes, your solution did the job. But sorry, RM, I accepted [Remy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) answer because of its elegance in realisation. Thank you for you useful thoughts!